# Get records whose values in a certain column contain any of a list of strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server which has several columns, one of which is "Payload", I want to select all records with payloads that contain any one of a (long) list of values.

Something like

```
select *
from myTable
where Payload contains ('%value1%', '%value2%', ...)
```

The list of values can be quite long so having "where Payload like '%value1%' or Payload like '%value2%' ... " isn't optimal. I also cannot alter the table in any way and it does not have an index.

What options, besides a cursor do I have?

Comment: Put these values in a (temporary) table. JOIN.

Comment: @jarlh, won't JOIN only select records where the values in the column match exactly, rather than one containing the other + other stuff?

Comment: Aside: Hopefully you are not going to be beset by the token parsing problem, e.g. finding "it" in "which they ate with a runcible spoon" because you aren't parsing out words.

Comment: @HABO, I'll be honest, I did not understand a bloody thing you just said. :D

Comment: Most of the times someone asks a question about "how do I find these strings in a column" they actually want to find _words_, not _strings_. They wind up using pattern matching, e.g. `... where MyColumn like '%eel%';`, to find recipes with the word "eel" and are surprised to find that it matches `'I was a teenage a steelhead.'` because "eel" is in "steelhead". So they get clever and split the column value on spaces (`String_Split( MyColumn, ' ' )')` to get "words" only to find that "steelhead" isn't in "I was a teenage steelhead, but I got better." because it splits out "steelhead,". Better?

Comment: @HABO, yes, mainly because I don't see "it" in your previous example which is what threw me off. I understand what you mean but I am not looking for words, I am, indeed, looking for strings.

Comment: And there's the problem: "it" hiding in "with".

Comment: @HABO, you sneaky devil, you! You got me good! :D An excellent example, if I do say so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with temp table as below:

```
insert the values into a temp table. 

create table temp (val varchar(15)) 

insert into temp values
('value1' ), ('value2' )

select *
from myTable
where Payload 
join temp on Payload like concat('%', val, '%')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using MySQL there's regex https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

```
select * from myTable where Payload rlike 'value1|value2';
```

Comment: Sorry, MS SQL Server. I'll edit the question.